# Is it legal to write and sell Instructions on how to play board games?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

For every board game that I am learning, I am writing 1-3 page instructions about the game and how to set up the game and play it.

Having 3 page summary of instructions (as opposed to 20 pages) makes it easy to return back to the game later and to quickly lookup a rule.

I plan to:

1. sell game instructions online for a few dollars
2. compose game instructions using my own words
3. briefly refer to names of characters, cards and game components as part of instructions
4. take pictures of certain board elements and add it to the game overview

Does any of the above require me to seek permission from the owner of the game copyright / trademark?

How can I minimize or avoid infringing on copyright or trademark?

Comment: Am I missing something? Every game I have ever bought or played comes with instructions in the box.

Comment: @DaleM I think he doesn't own the copyright to the board game and he doesn't have the permission of the copyright owner.

Comment: @NickODell I get that; what I don't get is why anyone would pay for his version of the instructions when, if they have the game, they have the official version.

Comment: @DaleM: Presumably, the OP plans to supplement the game instructions.  Some game instructions leave a lot to be desired.  Well-written Instruction supplements for complex games are very useful.  Most games already have many free online supplements or resources.  I'm sure that will make sales difficult for the OP.

Comment: Sorry I should explain it. Games come with rule books but many games I play have 20 or more pages of rules. I also find some of the rules hard to understand. Having 1-3 page overview and list of steps to setup and play game makes it easy to start playing the game again in the future?

Comment: @DennisCa It seems like you've got two different accounts here. You may want to [contact Stack Exchange to have them merged](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).